# Preciso fazer com que o php mostre apenas as 10 ultimas noticias

Tags: php, html, sql

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "conexao.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticia ORDER BY id DESC";
    $noticia = $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->close();
?>
<?php include "include/header.php" ?>
<?php
    if ($noticia->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row = $noticia->fetch_assoc()) {
      ?>

    <div class="card text-white bg-secondary my-5 py-4 text-center">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="text-white m-0"></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Content Row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo "{$row['titulo']}";?></h2>
            <p class="card-text"><?php echo "{$row['data_noticia']}";?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="noticia.php?id="<?php.$row['id'].;?>> Noticia</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-md-4 -->

    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
<?php include "include/footer.php" ?>
```

Usei esse codigo, aparece as noticias em ordem decrescente, mas quero que mostre so as 10 ultimas

Comment: Basta alterar a consulta SQL e adicionar um limite. Essa pergunta é sobre SQL, não sobre PHP ou HTML.

Comment: Não sabia que era sobre SQL, como altero a consulta/

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Limitar sua query já seria o suficiente:

`SELECT * FROM noticia ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;`

Answer (score 2):

Realmente a forma o @Ivan Ferrer respondeu já soluciona sua questão, outra forma de realizar essa verificação seria com:

```
SELECT * FROM noticia ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 10;
```

Comment: E por que essa seria uma outra forma se é a mesma coisa?